# Best EC2 Instance for Burst Data Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, bigdata

I need some advice on what type of EC2 instance to use for my data processing application. It's a Golang application that utilizes goroutines and channels. It scheduled to check a data source every 10 seconds and could process around one million entries into a database per hour.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't see why you need a burstable EC2 instance for this.

Comment: you might like to look at aws lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use T2 type of instance. It is suitable for Burstable Performance. You can read more about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/low-cost-burstable-ec2-instances/)

Also have a look at [how to choose right type of instances available in EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/choosing-the-right-ec2-instance-type-for-your-application/)